# Detect if the Printer Had Successfully Print the Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, printing

I was printing my site page using the code below:

```
window.print();
```

How will I know if the page was successfully/not successfuly printed by the printer? The reason why I want to do this is "to avoid reprinting the page twice". Each successful print is quite expensive in my case because I am printing an ID.

I am looking for all browser compatible solution. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do that :/

There is [window.onafterprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint) handler, but it is fired both when the user prints or aborts a print dialog. And it is not widely implemented too.

P. S. I don't see why you would want to know whether a print took place or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event which is available to track anything that has happened in the print dialog.

However there are events

- *onbeforeprint* which is fired before the dialog actually appears
- *onafterprint* is fired just before dialog appears but it is extremely hard to know whether the page actually printed

Both of them only work in firefox+6 I believe and higher versions of IE